# Can't download hadoop

Tags: tar, mirroring, hadoop, http-status-code-404

Am I taking crazy pills or is it impossible to download hadoop right now? I am looking at http://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.cgi/hadoop/common/ to find mirrors for it and absolutely none of them work for me. I keep getting 404 errors. It seems unlikely that no where on the internet could I get the hadoop.tar.gz package, so what is going on? Is there some reason why my computer would not be able to reach any of the mirrors?

Answer (score 1):

A 404 indicates resourcenotfound error.
Can you try [enter link description here](http://www-us.apache.org/dist/hadoop/common/stable/)

[http://www-us.apache.org/dist/hadoop/common/stable/hadoop-2.9.1.tar.gz](http://www-us.apache.org/dist/hadoop/common/stable/) for the 2.9 distribution of hadoop.
When am trying i could download tar file from the above URL.

Answer (score 0):

I also have problem with the URL you provide...

Maybe here is OK?:

http://hadoop.apache.org/releases.html

....maybe not....:-( sorry I think it is also down....

Here is OK, at least from my IP:

https://archive.apache.org/dist/hadoop/core/

Good luck